# Criteriabuilder like, how to do it for Long?

Tags: postgresql, jpa

i try use "like" method from Criteriabuilder for get all record based on pattern " 10% ".

I want get record where ID is - 101, 10002, 1003,1000 etc...

I've use this code:

```
Predicate p = cb.like(r.<String>get("ID").as(String.class), "10%")
```

but i got Exception where i see what postgres can't execute query like this:

```
SELECT ID, NAME, SOMETHING FROM TABLE WHERE ID LIKE 10%
```

**That is JPA (Glassfish 4.x) generate wrond query.**

Right query must like that :

```
SELECT ID, NAME, SOMETHING FROM TABLE WHERE CAST (ID as TEXT) LIKE '10%'
```

How to build query via Criteria API that i got a right query for postgres ?

**Updated:**

I try write a CAST function :

```
Expression<String> postgresqlCastFunction = cb.function("CAST", String.class, r.<String>get("ID").as(String.class));
Predicate p = cb.like(postgresqlCastFunction, "10%");
```

but got a query like this :

```
FROM TABLE WHERE (CAST(ID) LIKE ?)
```

, so, how to add need expression in function for this right result -

FROM TABLE WHERE (CAST(ID **as TEXT**) LIKE ?) ..

Comment: Check this post: [JPA Like Operator with Integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535084/jpa-like-operator-with-integer)

Comment: updated ^, please help me for write function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example implementation using PostgreSQL native [TO_CHAR](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-TABLE) function may look as follows:

**JPQL**

```
SELECT r FROM Records r 
WHERE FUNCTION('TO_CHAR', r.ID, 'FM9999999999') LIKE :pattern
```

**Criteria API**

```java
Path<String> id = r.get("ID");
Expression<String> format = cb.literal("FM9999999999");
Expression<String> function= cb.function("TO_CHAR", String.class, id, format);
ParameterExpression<String> pattern = cb.parameter(String.class, "pattern");
Predicate like = cb.like(function, pattern);
cq.where(like);
```

also you can build the query as an one-liner:

```java
cq.where(cb.like(cb.function("TO_CHAR", String.class, r.get("ID"), cb.literal("FM9999999999")), cb.parameter(String.class, "pattern")));
```

---

Execute the above query:

```java
Query q = em.createQuery(cq).setParameter("pattern", "10%");
```

Comment: Thx, it work as me need! But i change the 
" cb.parameter(String.class, "pattern"); " to "cb.literal("pattern"); " as your code get " Query argument pattern not found in the list of parameters provided during query execution ". 

i right ?

Comment: Glad I could help. You can treat cb.literal as constant and cb.parameter as variable. If you want to call query without using parameter then change `cb.parameter(String.class, "pattern")` to `cb.literal("10%")`.