# Best way to convert long column to String in Hibernate

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-criteria

I have a requirement that I need perform a like operation in hibernate criteria on one of the column in DB, the Data type for that column is "long", tried differently and browsed through but no luck, any suggestions would help.

Here is what I tried:

```
1) predicates.add(builder.like(root.<String>get("id"), "%"+params.getId()+"%"));
2) predicates.add(builder.like(root.get("id").as(String.class), "%"+params.getId()+"%"));
```

Answer (score 0):

An example implementation using PostgreSQL native [TO_CHAR](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-TABLE) function may look as follows:

**JPQL**

```
SELECT r FROM Records r 
WHERE FUNCTION('TO_CHAR', r.ID, 'FM9999999999') LIKE :pattern
```

**Criteria API**

```java
Path<String> id = r.get("ID");
Expression<String> format = cb.literal("FM9999999999");
Expression<String> function= cb.function("TO_CHAR", String.class, id, format);
ParameterExpression<String> pattern = cb.parameter(String.class, "pattern");
Predicate like = cb.like(function, pattern);
cq.where(like);
```

also you can build the query as an one-liner:

```java
cq.where(cb.like(cb.function("TO_CHAR", String.class, r.get("ID"), cb.literal("FM9999999999")), cb.parameter(String.class, "pattern")));
```

---

Execute the above query:

```java
Query q = em.createQuery(cq).setParameter("pattern", "10%");
```

Reference: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29257904/967808)